# Replace text between two DataFrames in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to replace/ablate terms within DataFrame if they appear within another DataFrame.

For example, below is the replace DataFrame that includes an ablate column and a replace column. I'm looking to replace any word that appears within the ablate row with whatever is in the replace row.

```
replace_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ablate': ['her', 'him', 'she', ' he ', 'woman', 'man'],
    'replace': ['', '', 'foo', '', '', 'bar']
})
```

For example, if given the below DataFrame with comment text...

```
comment_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'comment_text': [
         'She is going to work',
         'The man said to the woman, hello',
         'Another way of viewing this article is to ask:',
    ],
})
```

applying `replace_df` would result in the below:

```
return_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'comment_text': [
         'foo is going to work',
         'The bar said to the, hello',
         'Another way of viewing this article is to ask:',
    ],
})
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dict would be a more natural data structure for the replacements. With that in mind, how about:

```
replacements = dict(zip(replace_df['ablate'].tolist(), replace_df['replace'].tolist()))

def replace_substrings(string):
    string_list = string.split(" ")
    for idx, substring in enumerate(string_list):
        for k in replacements.keys():
            if substring.lower()[:len(k)] == k:
                string_list[idx] = substring.lower().replace(k, replacements[k])
    return " ".join(string_list).replace(" ,", ",")


comment_df['comment_text'].apply(replace_substrings)
```

which returns:

```
0                              foo is going to work
1                        The bar said to the, hello
2    Another way of viewing this article is to ask:
```

Comment: ooops, I'm missing your "woman": "" example....give me a minute.

Comment: Awesome. Ya a dict makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, updated...Sorry, my solution is pretty ugly but I have to get back to real work :D The punctuation, preserving upper cases and "man" in "woman" etc. is kind of tricky to deal with. Someone else might have a neater solution that catches the edge cases, but hopefully this gets you on the right track.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Building off [@fordy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4277212/fordy)'s example, you could achieve this in a fairly concise way:

```py
replacements = dict(zip(replace_df['ablate'].tolist(), replace_df['replace'].tolist()))

comment_df["comment_text"] = comment_df["comment_text"].str.lower().replace(replacements, regex=True)
```